# USB HID Codes mystery

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently writing out USB HID codes in Python 3....

```
NULL_CHAR = chr(0)
def write_report(report):
with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
    fd.write(report.encode())

# Press SHIFT + a = A
write_report(chr(32)+NULL_CHAR+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)
# Release all keys
write_report(NULL_CHAR*8)
```

My question:

By looking at the standard "USB HID Usage Tables" from USB.org ( v1.12 - 10-21-2004 - https://www.usb.org/document-library/hid-usage-tables-112 ) ...

I know from actively running the example above
( Using "USAGE ID" in Decimal FYI ), that **CHR(32)** is a **< SHIFT >**, but in the HID table it shows that a **Decimal (32)** is a Keyboard **< 3 >** or **< # >** ..

What's up with that ?

Am I using the wrong table, Should i be using ASCii codes instead of USB HID Keyboard codes ?

Is there a better/more accurate table of codes ?

Because if chr(32) is in reality a < SHIFT >, what then would be < 3 > ?

Is there an easier way to type Function Keys ( F1+F3+F5 ) in combination, in addition to full text lines, and issue them out over USB than the way i'm currently doing it ?

Any help to clear this up by the pro's here would be greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Not all of the bytes in the keyboard report are interpreted the same way.  One of them is a bitmap of modifier keys that are held down (this is the 32), and six of them are individual key codes for other keys that are pressed (the 4 is one of these).  The definitions for the modifiers byte don't appear to be in the file you linked to.

Comment: @jasonharper - Thanks !!!  Could you tell me where i could find a table that would list all those modifier keys ???

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still need the answer, but I figured out after a day of headache over the same thing.
The information you're sending always must be transferred as 8 bytes.
So from your example:

```
write_report(chr(32)+NULL_CHAR+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)
```

The chr(32) is Byte 0 (which is the modifier), then comes a null char at Byte 1, then the actual char at Byte 2, then another 5 nullchars, to make it 8.
Modifiers follow a different system from actual chars.

```
LCTRL  0x01
LSHIFT 0x02
LALT   0x04
LMETA  0x08
RCTRL  0x10
RSHIFT 0x20
RALT   0x40
RMETA  0x80
```

So the reason for 32 is because that's the decimal equivalent of 0x20 in hex.
Hope this helps you, or anyone else looking for this answer.